# How can I use Computed Column Specification to calculate a variable from other tables?

Tags: sql

can I use Computed Column Specification to calculate a variable from other tables?

I know how to use Computed Column Specification to calcuate a variable from a table. such as

```
(case when [LastWorkingDate] IS NULL then round(datediff(day,[EntryDate],getdate())/(365.25),(2)) else round(datediff(day,[EntryDate],[LastWorkingDate])/(365.25),(2)) end)
```

But how can I calculate a value from the other table?

I want to do as this but seems not good ...

```
select sum(Hour) from StaffInfo where year = 2012;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it is SQL Server. As far as I know the `computed column` term exists only there.

According to [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx) (emphasis is mine):

> A computed column is computed from an expression that can use other
>   columns in the **same** table.

Furthermore:

> The expression cannot be a subquery.

So, you can't have a subquery to calculate the `Sum(hour)` value from a different table.

You have a couple of options:

1. You can create a normal column and use `INSERT/UPDATE` trigger to update the value in this column as you insert or update records.
2. You can create a `VIEW`. In the view you will join the StaffInfo table and select the Sum(Hour) value as a column in the view

Comment: Thanks so much!! That's helps a lot!! and I have already used the View method~~~ but I don't know how to show the "View" in the ASP.NET ...